# Will ions in a solution emit radiation from an electric discharge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, plasma-physics

If I pump enough current through a water solution with ions in it, will the ions in the solution emit EM radiation as the water heats up to form a "spark"/plasma? Basically trying to make an Inductively Coupled Plasma-Optical Emission Spectrometer but simplifying the plasma generation by generating it directly in the solution using high currents.

Answer (score 0):

If you "pump current" through water you will generate $H_{2}$ and $O_{2}$ gas through a process called [electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis).  The two gases form at different locations, one near the cathode and one near the anode (I can never remember which).  If you were to create a spark near the $O_{2}$ side, you would likely cause a rapid combustion of said $O_{2}$ (assuming it's not completely pure $O_{2}$, which won't combust).

If you ramp up the current enough, the bigger issue initially will be heat.  You could dump MAs of current into the water and cause it to flash boil (or chemically split into $H_{2}$ and $O_{2}$, don't recall which is energetically favorable here).  Without a huge electrical potential, you would then cease to conduct the current as water vapor is not very conductive (well, pure water is an insulator as well).  I have no idea if it's possible to drive this quickly enough to cause a stable plasma without multiple other mechanical problems obstructing your goal (e.g., in principle you can dump as much current as you want into the system, but that doesn't mean the enclosure or current-carrying materials will handle it).

In summary, I am not sure ionizing water in this way is the most efficient method for generating plasmas in situ.  It would take a rather large amount of energy just to [disassociate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_(chemistry)) the $H_{2}O$ compound and then another large amount of energy to disassociate the $H_{2}$ and $O_{2}$, then even more energy to ionize the monatomic $H$ and $O$.  All of this would need to be done before the molecules could recombine.